# checkbox value not change the column of the table value in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have checkbox in my ruby on rails application like below:

```
<table>
      <% if c.CommunicationMode == "Email" and c.Private.to_s == "1" %>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <label class="checkbox inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ChkBx_Email" id="ChkBx_Email" value="1" checked = "checked">
                        Email
                 </label>
             </td>
         </tr>        
      <% else %>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <label class="checkbox inline">
                         <%= check_box_tag 'ChkBx_Email' %>
                         Email
                 </label>
             </td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
</table>
```

And in my `Communication` table I am below columns:

```
id | CommunicationMode | Private
1  | Email             | 1
```

You can see in the `Private` column of the table, I put value `1` : means checkbox is `checked`, and when I uncheck the checkbox, the `Private` column value replace from `1` to `0` like below:

```
id | CommunicationMode | Private
1  | Email             | 1
```

But when I check the checkbox again the `Private` column value is not replacing from `0` to `1`. 
And is the controller code:

```
  @user_communication=Communication.where(:UserID => current_user.id)
  if !@user_communication.blank?
    @user_communication.each do |c|
      if params[:settings][:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 1
        c.update_attribute( :Private, params[:settings][:ChkBx_Email] )
      elsif params[:settings][:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 0
        c.update_attribute( :Private, params[:settings][:ChkBx_Email] )
      end
    end
  end
```

Kindly suggest me waiting for reply.
Thanks

Comment: what are you getting in params[:settings][:ChkBx_Email].to_i?

Comment: when I uncheck the checkbox I get `0` value in the `params[:settings][:ChkBx_Email].to_i` and after that when I check the checkbox it always get `0` value. ? why

Answer (score 2):

you need to change input name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="settings[ChkBx_Email]" id="settings[ChkBx_Email]" value="1" checked = "checked">
```

or controller code:

```
      if params[:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 1
        c.update_attribute( :Private, params[:ChkBx_Email] )
      elsif params[:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 0
        c.update_attribute( :Private, params[:ChkBx_Email] )
      end
```

Comment: I am using your piece of code, But its not check again the checkbox means it not replace the `Private` column vale from `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

change your controller code to this:-

```
  if params[:ChkBx_Email] == 1
        c.update_attribute( :Private, params[:ChkBx_Email] )
      elsif params[:ChkBx_Email] == 0
        c.update_attribute( :Private, params[:ChkBx_Email] )
      end
```

taking into account that you are receiving the checked/unchecked values in the params